# OpenCV: howto use mask parameter for feature point detection (SURF)

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, surf, roi

I want to limit a SurfFeatureDetector to a set of regions (mask). For a test I define only a single mask:

```
Mat srcImage; //RGB source image
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(srcImage.size(), srcImage.type());
Mat roi(mask, cv::Rect(10,10,100,100));
roi = Scalar(255, 255, 255);
SurfFeatureDetector detector();
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect(srcImage, keypoints, roi); // crash
//detector.detect(srcImage, keypoints); // does not crash
```

When I pass the "roi" as the mask I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mask.empty() || (mask.type() == CV_8UC1 && mask.size() == image.size())) in detect, file /Users/ux/Downloads/OpenCV-iOS/OpenCV-iOS/../opencv-svn/modules/features2d/src/detectors.cpp, line 63
```

What is wrong with this? How can I correctly pass a mask to the SurfFeatureDetector's "detect" method?

Regards,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two things about the mask.

- the mask should be a 1-channel matrix of 8-bit unsigned chars, which translates to opencv type `CV_8U`. In your case the mask is of type srcImage.type(), which is a 3-channel matrix
- you are passing `roi` to the detector but you should be passing `mask`. When you are making changes to `roi`, you are also changing `mask`.

the following should work

```
Mat srcImage; //RGB source image
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(srcImage.size(), CV_8U);  // type of mask is CV_8U
// roi is a sub-image of mask specified by cv::Rect object
Mat roi(mask, cv::Rect(10,10,100,100));
// we set elements in roi region of the mask to 255 
roi = Scalar(255);  
SurfFeatureDetector detector();
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect(srcImage, keypoints, mask);     // passing `mask` as a parameter
```

Comment: I think it should be `Scalar(255);` as the mask is 1-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

I tacked your ROI code onto some existing code I was working on, with the following changes it worked for me

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(frame.size(), CV_8UC1);  //NOTE: using the type explicitly
cv::Mat roi(mask, cv::Rect(10,10,100,100));
roi = cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255);

//SURF feature detection
const int minHessian = 400;
cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect(frame, keypoints, mask);              //NOTE: using mask here, NOT roi
cv::Mat img_keypoints; 
drawKeypoints(frame, keypoints, img_keypoints, cv::Scalar::all(-1), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);
cv::imshow("input image + Keypoints", img_keypoints);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Without the changes to the type and the use of `mask` instead of `roi` as your mask, I'd get a runtime error as well. This makes sense, as the detect method wants a mask -- it should be the same size as the original image, and roi isn't (it's a 100x100 rectangle). To see this visually, try displaying the mask and the roi

```
cv::imshow("Mask", mask);
cv::waitKey(0);

cv::imshow("ROI", roi);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

The type has to match also; the mask should be single channel, while your image type is likely of type 16, which maps to `CV_8UC3`, a triple channel image

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to apply the same for irregular mask then:

```
Mat& obtainIregularROI(Mat& origImag, Point2f topLeft, Point2f topRight, Point2f botLeft, Point2f botRight){

        static Mat black(origImag.rows, origImag.cols, origImag.type(), cv::Scalar::all(0));
        Mat mask(origImag.rows, origImag.cols, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));
        vector< vector<Point> >  co_ordinates;
        co_ordinates.push_back(vector<Point>());
        co_ordinates[0].push_back(topLeft);
        co_ordinates[0].push_back(botLeft);
        co_ordinates[0].push_back(botRight);
        co_ordinates[0].push_back(topRight);
        drawContours( mask,co_ordinates,0, Scalar(255),CV_FILLED, 8 );

       // origImag.copyTo(black,mask);
        //BasicAlgo::getInstance()->writeImage(black);
        return mask;  // returning the mask only
    }
```

Then as usual, generate SIFT/SURF/... pointer

// Create smart pointer for SIFT feature detector.

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> SIFT_FeatureDetector = FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
vector<KeyPoint> SIFT_Keypoints;
vector<KeyPoint> SIFT_KeypointsRotated; 
Mat maskedImg = ImageDeformationOperations::getInstance()->obtainIregularROI( rotatedImg,rotTopLeft,rotTopRight,rotBotLeft,rotBotRight);
SIFT_FeatureDetector->detect(rotatedImg, SIFT_KeypointsRotated, maskedImg);
Mat outputSIFTKeyPt;
drawKeypoints(rotatedImg, SIFT_KeypointsRotated, outputSIFTKeyPt, keypointColor, DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);
```